# How can I make a Cordova/Angularjs/Ionic app with one image you can tap to view fullscreen?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm not very familiar with Cordova/Angularjs/Ionic, but I'm working with an otherwise complete app. All I want to do is display an image that can be tapped once to view it in fullscreen. I know a lot of apps can do that. They also give users the chance to copy, email, or download that image into their camera roll. Are there any plugins I should know about that make that possible? I've searched extensively and can't seem to find any documentation around such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this plugin: 
https://github.com/keensoft/FullScreenImage-Cordova-Plugin

Comment: This doesn't really work except for images that are bundled along with the app. If you are going to be downloading images to the device filesystem this does not work well